# Why does my for loop stop after one execution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, for-loop

I created an array with four objects. I am attempting to show a new random object in the array each time a button (HAPPY) is clicked, using a FOR loop. However, on button click, the loop only runs once with no error messages given. I have looked through other peoples' for loops and they are similar or identical to mine. So I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

I know that a small part of code is missing to bring everything together. I suspected it was something to do with [i] and have tried adding this to different parts of the code - to no avail.

Any help appreciated, thank you. JS Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/manoj1234/4yd2jup8/1/)

```js
window.onload = () => {
  /* HTML ELEMENTS */

  var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");

  var welcomeButton = document.getElementById("welcome-button");
  var welcomeBox = document.getElementById("welcome-box");

  var introQuestion = document.getElementById("intro-question");

  var happyButton = document.getElementById("happy");
  const nextVerseButton = document.querySelector(".box-button");

  const slider = document.querySelector(".happy-slider");
  const bibleBox = document.querySelector(".happy-bible-box");

  var pageTitle = document.getElementById("title");
  var pageVerse = document.getElementById("verse");

  const happyVerses = [{
      title: "Psalm 28:7",
      verse: "The Lord is my strength and shield. I trust him with all my heart. He helps me, and my heart is filled with joy.I burst out in songs of thanksgiving."
    },
    {
      title: "Philippians 4:4",
      verse: "Rejoice in the Lord always. Again I will say, rejoice!"
    },
    {
      title: "John 15:11",
      verse: "These things have I spoken to you, that My joy may remain in you, and that your joy may be full."
    },
    {
      title: "2 Corinthians 6:10",
      verse: "Our hearts ache, but we always have joy. We are poor, but we give spiritual riches to others.We own nothing, and yet we have everything."
    },
  ];

  console.log(happyVerses);

  // Random verse
  const randomVerse = happyVerses[Math.floor(Math.random() * happyVerses.length)];
  let newTitle = randomVerse.title;
  let newVerse = randomVerse.verse;

  welcomeButton.onclick = () => {
    welcomeBox.style.display = "none";
    introQuestion.style.display = "flex";
  }

  happyButton.onclick = () => {
    introQuestion.style.display = "none";
    arrow.style.display = "block";
    bibleBox.style.display = "block";

  }

  arrow.onclick = () => {
    arrow.style.display = "none";
    introQuestion.style.display = "flex";
    bibleBox.style.display = "none";
  }

  changeText = () => {
    pageTitle.innerHTML = newTitle;
    pageVerse.innerHTML = newVerse;
  }

  nextVerseButton.onclick = () => {
    for (i = 0; i < happyVerses.length; i++) {
      changeText();
    };

    i++;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.fade {
  transition: ease 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black !important;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.page-wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*Wrapper width*/
  margin-left: 5%;
  /*Nice space between content and device border*/
  margin-right: 5%;
  /*Nice space between content and device border*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#arrow {
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header-2 h1 {
  color: white;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0E7CFF;
}

#main-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#welcome-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#welcome h1 {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#welcome-button {
  padding: 12px 30px 12px 30px;
  border: solid 1.5px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

#button-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#button-div button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
}

#intro-question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

#intro-question button {
  padding: 12px;
  border: solid 1.5px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

#intro-question button:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#intro-question button:nth-child(4) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#intro-question h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.happy-bible-box {
  color: white;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  transition: ease 0.3s;
}

#title {
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.happy-bible-box p {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2', cursive;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.box-button {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1.5px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina 2', cursive;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Bible</title>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cd801faa65.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhaina+2:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">

    <div class="page-wrap">

      <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="arrow"></i>

      <div id="welcome-box">
        <h1>Welcome to Bible</h1>
        <button id="welcome-button">Let's go</button>
      </div>

      <div id="intro-question">
        <h1>How are you feeling today?</h1>

        <div id="button-div">
          <button id="happy">Happy</button>
          <button id="anxious">Anxious</button>
          <button id="worried">Worried</button>
          <button id="lustful">Confused</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <article class="happy-bible-box">
        <h2 id="title">John 15:11</h2>
        <p id="verse">These things have I spoken to you, that My joy may remain in you, and that your joy may be full.</p>

        <button class="box-button">Show me another</button>
      </article>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't need the incrementor after the execution, for starters. Remove the second `i++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get random verse for once :

`let randomVerse = happyVerses[Math.floor(Math.random()*happyVerses.length)];
let newTitle = randomVerse.title;
let newVerse = randomVerse.verse;`

Put this in the changetext function to get random verse every time.
Like this:

```
  changeText = () => {
let randomVerse = happyVerses[Math.floor(Math.random()*happyVerses.length)];
    pageTitle.innerHTML = randomVerse.title;
    pageVerse.innerHTML = randomVerse.verse;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `randomVerse` into `changeText()` function to get it executed everytime `nextVerseButton` is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to for loop, just run the change function:  changeText();

Comment: This is correct. I have no clue why I never thought of this!

Comment: Any idea on how to stop the next random verse from being the same as the one shown already on screen?

Comment: You can save the previous verse inside a variable and check in the next step if the new verse was the same as the previous verse,make a random verse again

Comment: I added this but it doesn't work     let oldVerse = randomVerse;

        if ( oldVerse = randomVerse){
            changeAngryText();
        }

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is a little confused. You need to get another random verse, your for loop is currently just setting the same thing everytime

```
nextVerseButton.onclick = () => {
 let randomVerse = happyVerses[Math.floor(Math.random()*happyVerses.length)];
 let newTitle = randomVerse.title;
 let newVerse = randomVerse.verse;
 changeText();
}
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You are setting the newTitle and newVerse variables at this point in the script, but changeText wouldn't know about them.
The variables should be passed as function parameters to changeText, or you should "let" them at the top of the script (as they are in the original script) and just overwrite them here with the "let".